# Edit system dump (core file) and write to a new file in WinDBG

Tags: windows, windbg, coredump, crash-dumps

I loaded a core file into winDBG and made the required changes to it. The problem is, I need to write it back. I need to make changes to the core since I'm testing a debugger. I know about using `.writemem` but I'm not sure what the 3rd parameter should be.

I believe the syntax is:

`.writemem <path to file> 0xbeginning-address L?end-address`

ps: I tried using a hex editor but it does NOT show me virtual addresses.  All it displays is the non-memory mapped rendering of the core file.

Comment: I did think of using .dump but the process isn't running. Technically, I could edit a running process's memory and execute a .dump but it isn't always an option. This is my current, working methodology: View the data as Bytes in WinDBG, copy the memory I want to edit, find the memory matching the data stored in my copy-buffer in the Hex Editor; edit the memory in place respecting the endianess and then save the core in the Hex Editor. A little tedious but it works like a charm.

Comment: WinDbg can create another dump from an existing one with `.dump`. So you can edit the memory (`ed`, `.writemem`, etc) then save out a new file.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand what you try to achieve, but I have successfully used the  following:
    =========================Move date from dump into memory====
    .writemem c:\Illmess.bin 065bcab0  065beb50
    Writing 20a1 bytes.....
    .readmem C:\Illmess.bin 0x036cea48  L20a1
    ===================================================

Comment: I can use writemem to write segments of memory to a file but I want to edit a small segment of a core file and write it back to the same core file or create a new one.I have come to the conclusion that WinDBG cannot do this. The most it can do it write memory to a file, but it cant create a valid core* file.